# Help complete an exercise - Computing Determinant/Solution to 3$\times$3 matrix

Tags: matrices, determinant

The following is an excerpt from a book I am using:
[image]

So, now I would like to compute $x_2$ and $x_3$ using the same approach that the author used to compute $x_1$. Here's my attempt for $x_2$:

> Assume the choice of $c_1,c_2$ and $c_3$ is such that in the system obtained, the terms with $x_1$ and $x_3$ is 0. We therefore obtain
>
> $\begin{cases} c_1a_{11} + c_2 a_{21} + c_3 a_{31} = 0\\
>                 c_1a_{13} + c_2 a_{23} + c_3 a_{33} = 0
> \end{cases}$
>
> Solving for $c_1$, $c_2$ and $c_3$:
>
> $c_1 = \left|\begin{array} {cc} a_{21} & a_{31}\\
>                                 a_{23} & a_{33}
>  \end{array} \right|$
>
> $c_2 = -\left|\begin{array} {cc} a_{11} & a_{31} \\
>                                   a_{13} & a_{33} \end{array}   \right|$
>
> $c_3 = \left| \begin{array} {cc} a_{11} & a_{31} \\
>                                   a_{13} & a_{23}\end{array}\right|$
>
> Solving $(c_1 a_{12} + c_2 a_{22} + c_3 a_{32})x_2 = c_1b_1 + c_2b_2 + c_3b_3$
>
> $\begin {array} {cc} \left[ a_{12} \left|\begin{array} {cc} a_{21} & a_{31}\\
>                                 a_{23} & a_{33}
>  \end{array} \right| - a_{22} \left|\begin{array} {cc} a_{11} & a_{31} \\
>                                   a_{13} & a_{33} \end{array}   \right| +a_{32} \left| \begin{array} {cc} a_{11} & a_{31} \\
>                                   a_{13} & a_{23}\end{array}\right| \right] x_2 \\ =  
> b_1 \left|\begin{array} {cc} a_{21} & a_{31}\\
>                                 a_{23} & a_{33}
>  \end{array} \right| - b_2 \left|\begin{array} {cc} a_{11} & a_{31} \\
>                                   a_{13} & a_{33} \end{array}   \right| +b_3 \left| \begin{array} {cc} a_{11} & a_{31} \\
>                                   a_{13} & a_{23}\end{array}\right| \end{array} $

I don't know what to do next. My coefficient of $x_2$ is not the same as the coefficient of $x_1$ in equation 2.8. But according to the author's answer, the coefficient for $x_1$, $x_2$ and $x_3$ are the same since all 3 have the same denominator.

I would appreciate it if someone can provide a step by step explanation of the manipulations I need to do.

Thank you in advance for any help provided.

Answer (score 1):

Your coefficient of $x_2$ is $\left|\begin{array} {ccc} a_{12} & a_{11} & a_{13}\\
                            a_{22} & a_{21} & a_{23}\\
                            a_{32} & a_{31} & a_{33}                               
 \end{array} \right|$

It is the same as the coefficient of $x_1$ up to the sign and is obtained oout the last by transposing columns.

Comment: Is there an alternative way to show that the two coefficients are equal? The text I am using has not made any mention up to this point of transposing columns to compute the determinant.

Comment: If you cannot transpose, then calculate this determinant by definition $(2.9)$ and check that it coincides with the coefficient of $x_1$ (up to the sign).

Answer (score 0):

You might find that this is helpful:  http://m.youtube.com/watch?v=vJLGWpob0T8&desktop_uri=%2Fwatch%3Fv%3DvJLGWpob0T8 . He talks through the $4\times 4$ case first for extra clarity. His other videos are great for this stuff too.

Answer (score 0):

Your calculation of $c_3$ is incorrect: it should read
$$ c_3 = \left|
\begin{array} {cc} a_{11} & a_{21} \\
a_{13} & a_{23} \end{array}  \right|$$

I believe that this rectifies all of your problems. When you use this value of $c_3$, the coefficient of $x_2$ is then
$$a_{12} \left|\begin{array} {cc} a_{21} & a_{31}\\
                                a_{23} & a_{33}
 \end{array} \right| - a_{22} \left|\begin{array} {cc} a_{11} & a_{31} \\
                                  a_{13} & a_{33} \end{array}   \right| +a_{32} \left| \begin{array} {cc} a_{11} & a_{21} \\
                                  a_{13} & a_{23}\end{array}\right| \\
= a_{12}(a_{21}a_{33} -a_{23}a_{31}) - a_{22}(a_{11}a_{33} - a_{31}a_{13}) + a_{32}(a_{11}a_{23} - a_{13}a_{21}) \\
= a_{11}(a_{32}a_{23} - a_{22}a_{33}) - a_{21}(a_{32}a_{13}-a_{12}a_{33}) + a_{31}(a_{22}a_{13} - a_{12}a_{23}) \\
= - \left| \begin{array} {ccc} a_{11} & a_{12} & a_{13} \\
a_{21} & a_{22} & a_{23} \\
a_{31} & a_{32} & a_{33}\\
\end{array} \right|$$

which is $-1$ times the coefficient of $x_1$ as given in the text. However, this is rectified as the right-hand side of your equation gives $-1$ times the numerator of $x_2$ as given in the text:

$$b_1 \left| 
\begin{array}{cc} a_{21} & a_{31}\\ a_{23} & a_{33}\\ \end{array} \right|- b_2 \left| \begin{array} {cc} a_{11} & a_{31} \\
                                  a_{13} & a_{33} \\ \end{array}   \right| +b_3 \left| \begin{array} {cc} a_{11} & a_{21} \\
                                  a_{13} & a_{23}\\ \end{array}\right| \\
= b_1(a_{21}a_{33} - a_{31}a_{23}) - b_2(a_{11}a_{33} - a_{31}a_{13}) + b_3(a_{11}a_{23} - a_{21}a_{13}) \\
= -a_{11}(b_2a_{33} - b_3a_{23}) + a_{21}(b_1a_{33}-b_3a_{13}) - a_{31}(b_1a_{33} - b_2a_{13}) \\
=- \left| \begin{array} {ccc} a_{11} & b_1 & a_{13} \\
a_{21} & b_2 & a_{23} \\
a_{31} & b_3 & a_{33}\\
\end{array} \right|$$

which recovers the formula for $x_2$ as given in the text.

Comment: Could you please show me how'd you got $c_3$?

Comment: It is through the same method that you used to obtain to find $c_1$ and $c_2$: solving from the system of equations $c1a11+c2a21+c3a31=0$ and $c1a13+c2a23+c3a33=0$. I believe this is explained in equation 2.5 of your text, as the excerpt you posted shows

Comment: Okay, I made a mistake. Just one more thing. How can you tell that $= a_{12}(a_{21}a_{33} -a_{23}a_{31}) - a_{22}(a_{11}a_{33} - a_{31}a_{13}) + a_{32}(a_{11}a_{23} - a_{13}a_{21}) \\
= a_{11}(a_{32}a_{23} - a_{22}a_{33}) - a_{21}(a_{32}a_{13}-a_{12}a_{33}) + a_{31}(a_{22}a_{13} - a_{12}a_{23}) \\
$? The text has not yet established that the expansion from different rows gives the same determinant.

Comment: This comes from algebraic manipulation: I expanded out the products and then combined the terms containing $a_{11}, a_{21}$ and $a_{31}$.